# How to group data and create bins?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following DataFrame df (a small extract is given):

```
time_diff   avg_qty_per_day
1.450000    1.0
1.483333    1.0
1.500000    1.0
2.516667    1.0
2.533333    1.0
2.533333    1.5
3.633333    1.8
3.644567    5.0
```

How can I group it into bins in order to get the following result?:

```
1   3
2   3.5
3   6.8
```

The size of a bin should be configurable.

Comment: It's not quite clear how you want to group the elements? What are you categories for instance?

Comment: @rammelmuller: In my example the bin size is 1 and bins are created based on the values of `time_diff`. The second column in the result is the sum of `avg_qty_per_day` for a corresponding bin. But I want to have the size of bins flexible, so that I can easily change it to 2 or 3 or whatever instead of default 1.

Comment: How about a bin size of 2.8?

Comment: Ah I see - generally I would recommend a fixed number of bins rather than a fixed width though.

Comment: if you need equal sized buckets may be you can use `pd.qcut`, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.qcut.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [-np.inf, 2, 3, np.inf]
labels=[1,2,3]
df = df['avg_qty_per_day'].groupby(pd.cut(df['time_diff'], bins=bins, labels=labels)).sum()
print (df)
time_diff
1    3.0
2    3.5
3    6.8
Name: avg_qty_per_day, dtype: float64
```

If want check labels:

```
bins = [-np.inf, 2, 3, np.inf]
labels=[1,2,3]
df['label'] = pd.cut(df['time_diff'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
   time_diff  avg_qty_per_day label
0   1.450000              1.0     1
1   1.483333              1.0     1
2   1.500000              1.0     1
3   2.516667              1.0     2
4   2.533333              1.0     2
5   2.533333              1.5     2
6   3.633333              1.8     3
7   3.644567              5.0     3
```

Comment: So, should I manually define `labels` and `bins`? what if I have thousands of bins?

Comment: Oh, I can use this: `bins = np.arange(df['time_diff'].min(), df['time_diff'].max()+2, 2)`

Comment: Ok, but is there an easy way to generate `labels` automatically for each bin?

Comment: maybe simpliest `labels= np.arange(1, len(bins))`